# Limit Value Question-To find the value of a.

Tags: limits

[image]

I did this problem,by rearranging and equating the coefficients.
But,that process is not so clear and logical.
Can,anyone give me a definite process for this?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

If you replace $x$ by $a$ in the expression, you have to find $a$ such that $$\frac{a^2+b}{a^2+3a-4}=4$$ If you developt the expression, you then arrive to $$3a^2+12 a-(16+b)=0$$ which is just a quadratic equation in $a$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Now,should i equate the coefficients?

Comment: Solve the quadratic for $a$.